# Get python datetime from polars datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

How do I get the python timestamp from the polars datetime object (which is a polars Expression)?

```py
import polars as pl
pl_timestamp = pl.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=5).dt.with_time_zone("UTC")
py_timestamp = ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [polars.select](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.select.html#polars.select) to run Polars Expressions without a context.

```py
pl.select(pl_timestamp)
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────┐
│ datetime                │
│ ---                     │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       │
╞═════════════════════════╡
│ 2020-06-05 00:00:00 UTC │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

From here, you can use indexing to convert to a Python object.

```py
pl.select(pl_timestamp)[0, 0]
```

```
>>> pl.select(pl_timestamp)[0, 0]
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 5, 0, 0)
```

##### Edit

The timezone information is maintained.  For example:

```py
pl_timestamp = pl.datetime(year=2020, month=6, day=5).dt.replace_time_zone("Europe/London")

pl.select(pl_timestamp)[0, 0]
```

```
>>> pl.select(pl_timestamp)[0, 0]
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/London'))
```

Comment: I've added an example with a time zone other than UTC to demonstrate that the time zone info is maintained.